# Select data from date range in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a trouble trying get a data in DB2 SQL.
I have a table Name `StProdMoves` and it holds data like this

```
ProdName | Status  | Brand | Type  | Date(Numeric)
----------+---------+-------+-------+-----------
ORANGE    | 10      |  SBR  |  IN   | 20181217105640
APPLE     | 10      |  SBR  |  IN   | 20181220143520
GARLIC    | 20      |  SBR  |  IN   | 20190107095740
APPLE     | 20      |  JUM  |  OUT  | 20190107121050
ORANGE    | 20      |  AUR  |  OUT  | 20190110164530
ORANGE    | 20      |  AUR  |  IN   | 20190110000000
GARLIC    | 10      |  SBR  |  OUT  | 20190211000000
```

Now what is the query if I want to select sales data between two dates from a date range?

For example, I want to select the products that stayed in the range `31/12/2018` and `07/01/2019` and brand=SBR and Status=10.

Edit:
I trying get the data using this query, but not all products selected show in that range of dates, then show a result like this:

```
SELECT * FROM StProdMoves WHERE DATE(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(Date), 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')) BETWEEN '31/12/2018' AND '07/01/2019' AND Brand='SBR' AND Status=10
```

Later as ProducName, Status, Brand, DateIn and DateOut where show all products exist in this date or range of date, like this

```
 ProdName | Status  | Brand |  DateIn  | DateOut
----------+---------+-------+-------+-----------
ORANGE    | 10      |  SBR  | 20181217 | ---
APPLE     | 10      |  SBR  | 20181220 | ---
PEAR      | 10      |  SBR  | 20181120 | 20190106
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the datatype of column `Date`?

Comment: the Datatype of column Date is numeric, but i can convert to Date using DATE(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(Date), 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))

Comment: @Taikun: given the format of your numbers, you can simply do numeric comparison... See my updated answer.

Comment: I had updated the information, i'm trying to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your dates as `Numeric` values in such a format as you provided, the most efficient way to query your table with `DATE` parameters should be like below:

```
select *
from (
          select 20181217105640 from sysibm.sysdummy1
union all select 20181220143520 from sysibm.sysdummy1
) StProdMoves (DateNumeric)
where 
    DateNumeric > bigint(varchar_format(DATE('2018-12-18'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
and DateNumeric < bigint(varchar_format(DATE('2019-01-06'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'));
```

We translate the `Date` input parameters to the `Numeric` timestamp representation of your data in such a way.

Comment: Lower bound on date/time queries (especially here) should be lower-bound inclusive, `>=`, or you'll drop anything for midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
select * from StProdMoves where Date >= '2018-12-31' and Date <= '2019-01-06'
```

Comment: upper bound on date/time queries (especially here) should be upper-bound exclusive, `<`, or you'll count anything at midnight twice: once for the "current" bucket, and once for the "next" bucket, when that shows up.

Answer (score 0):

This question is all about how to form the `WHERE` clause of the query.

---

If column `Date` is of a [string datatype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_stringdatatypes.html) (like `VARCHAR(n)`, `CHARACTER(n)`, and so on), then, given their format, it is possible to do string comparison like:

```
DateColumn >= '2018-12-31' and DateColumn < '2019-01-06'
```

---

If you are actually dealing with a [`DATE` datatype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_datetimetimestamp.html), you can convert your strings to the corresponding datatypes before comparing, like:

```
DateColumn >= DATE('2018-12-31') and DateColumn < DATE('2019-01-06')
```

Of if you are dealing with a `TIMESTAMP`:

```
DateColumn >= TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31 00:00:00') AND DateColumn < TIMESTAMP('2019-01-06 00:00:00')
```

---

**EDIT**

If you are dealing with a numeric datatype (as show in your edited question), well you can simply do numeric comparison:

```
DateColumn >= 20181231000000 and DateColumn < 20190106000000
```

---

NB: it is usually not a good idea to name columns like a RDBMS function or a datatype. I renamed your column from `Date` to `DateColumn` in the examples.

Comment: `DateColumn > 20181231000000` doesn't work in Db2 for LUW & DB2 for IBM i. The following works, for example: `DateColumn > timestamp(to_char(20181231000000))`. If your last example really works, then what's your Db2 version and platform?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein: this expression was meant to answer the case when `DateColumn` is *numeric*, not *date*-like datatype. Wouldn't that work in this particular case?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the data type of `DateColumn` in your example.

Comment: Lower bound on date/time queries (especially here) should be lower-bound inclusive, `>=`, or you'll drop anything for midnight.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM "StProdMoves"
WHERE "Date(Numeric)" BETWEEN DECIMAL(DATE('2018-12-31')) * 1000000  
                          AND DECIMAL(DATE('2019-01-07')) * 1000000 + 999999
```